What’s a good chip for raw GPS data for astrodynamics purposes?
I have a Raspberry Pi and a Beitian 180 GPS receiver, but it only outputs NMEA messages with observables like the satellites azimuth/elevation, local UTC time, etc. I’m planning on converting the GPS so it gives my lat/long into IJK coords and implementing Gauss’s method with the data, but I really want the raw GPS/GNSS data to get the satellite transmission timestamp, the ephemeris, the satellite positions, and so on. Is there any way to extract that from a device like this, or should I just go for something like a u-blox module.
Any recommendations for GPS modules that I could get the raw (not the true raw like the radio signals, but the ephemeris and pseudoranges and the like) data from without too much difficulty to practice some astrodynamics?

I'm no expert, but a u-Blox module will definitely give you lots of interesting data to play with and learn from. cf. https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=u-blox and https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A102305+u-blox just for example. They come in a number of flavors, and prices, and can be bought in many outlets, including online resellers and hobbyists. Even if one doesn't address all your needs, you may find it rewarding to give one a spin.

@uhoh by the way I ended up getting the ublox chip and it’s been fantastic! Getting the satellite navigation messages and ephemeris data was super easy, and I’m hyped to work with it more. Maybe I’ll get to test it in the arctic one day…

That's excellent, glad to hear it! If you can find a way to explain why a module like that worked for you (without sounding like an advertisement for a specific company) please feel free to post an answer. The details may be helpful to future readers, and if they see that the question has an answer they're more inclined to stop and read it. Thanks!

@uhoh good point, I'll definitely do so after I mess around with it a bit more.
